# Making the entries of bordermatrix smaller

Tags: amsmath, amsart, bordermatrix

How do I make the entries in bordermatrix smaller?

```
 \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{stackrel} 
 \usepackage{courier}


 \makeatletter
 \newif\if@borderstar
 \def\bordermatrix{\@ifnextchar*{%
   \@borderstartrue\@bordermatrix@i}{\@borderstarfalse\@bordermatrix@i*}%
  }
  \def\@bordermatrix@i*{\@ifnextchar[{\@bordermatrix@ii}{\@bordermatrix@ii[()]}}
  \def\@bordermatrix@ii[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
  \m@th\@tempdima8.75\p@\setbox\z@\vbox{%
   \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\kern 2\p@\global\let\cr\endline }}%
   \ialign {$##$\hfil\kern 2\p@\kern\@tempdima & \thinspace %
   \hfil $##$\hfil && \quad\hfil $##$\hfil\crcr\omit\strut %
   \hfil\crcr\noalign{\kern -\baselineskip}#2\crcr\omit %
   \strut\cr}}%
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{\unhbox\@ne\unskip\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{%
   $\kern\wd\@ne\kern -\@tempdima\left\@firstoftwo#1%
     \if@borderstar\kern2pt\else\kern -\wd\@ne\fi%
   \global\setbox\@ne\vbox{\box\@ne\if@borderstar\else\kern 2\p@\fi}%
   \vcenter{\if@borderstar\else\kern -\ht\@ne\fi%
     \unvbox\z@\kern-\if@borderstar2\fi\baselineskip}%
     \if@borderstar\kern-2\@tempdima\kern2\p@\else\,\fi\right\@secondoftwo#1 $%
   }\null \;\vbox{\kern\ht\@ne\box\tw@}%
  \endgroup
   }
  \makeatother


 \begin{document}


 \[ \hspace{-10mm}
 \bordermatrix[{[]}]{
 &a_{11} &a_{21} &a_{31} &a_{41} &b_{11} &b_{12} &b_{21} &b_{22} &b_{11} 
 &b_{12} &b_{13} 
 &b_{21} &b_{22} &b_{23} &b_{31} &b_{32} &b_{33} &b_{41} &b_{42} &b_{43} &b_{44} \cr 
 &1000      &1000 &1000 &1000 &1000     &1000  &1000 &1000 &1000& 1000& 1000&1000
 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 &1000  &1000  &1000  &1000 \cr 
 &1000      &1000 &1000 &1000 &1000     &1000  &1000 &1000 &1000& 1000& 1000&1000
 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1000 &1000  &1000  &1000  &1000 \cr 
 }
 \]  




 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example:

```
foo

\tiny
 \[ 
 \bordermatrix[{[]}]{
   ...     
 } 
 \]  
\normalsize

bar
```

There is also a `kbordermatrix` with some more features: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/ Examples: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf